# Word Interop with Multiple Versions

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interop

I want to support all Office suites in one application using Office Interop.

I was able to do this in Visual Basic by making use of `CreateObject()`? 
The problem was that I wasn't able to see the functions up-front and had to jump around between docs to get it done (Due to `Object` being used).

If I use a factory pattern and have an implementation for each version of Office, would it work?

Example:

```
Factory->ABaseOffice GetImplementation(string office_version)
```

Returns an instance of `ABaseOffice` which is implemented by `Office2000` and `OfficeXP`.

This way if a new Office version comes out I just have to write the speciffic code for it and not be bothered about the previous versions or depending on 3rd party software.

I don't want to follow the [COM/Interop - Supporting Multiple Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/258972/158288) route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes - in theory this works... the problem is that you definitely can't reference different versions of the Interop-DLLs in the same project... so you will still have to use the late binding approach for the implementations of the `ABaseOffice` interface

UPDATE - as per comments:

In theory the described option (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx) would allow for adding those references... several reasons not to do so:

- these are much more than 2 versions of Interop DLL
- the DLL name ist the same IIRC (which poses a problem not addressed in that article!)
- the result would be really hard to understand/maintain/debug

Comment: Why can't he reference different versions of the interop dlls ? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx